# Unable to build Solr 8.1.1 Docker Image for Sitecore 9.3 Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a Sitecore 9.3 container using Docker using [Sitecore Docker Images](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images). So before actually creating the Sitecore container, I'm trying to create a Solr container using openjdk as Base Image.

Steps that I have already completed so far:

1. Installed Docker for Windows
2. Pulled Docker image for windows nanoserver:1903, aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-1903 and servercore:1903
3. Cloned [Sitecore Docker Images](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images) with the commit "de980689850322f6fef8205ee89cf544e720b732" (There was an issue with the latest commit at the time)
4. Downloaded Sitecore 9.3 WDPs into the folder \windows\9.3.0\sitecore-assets. The assets folder looked like: [image]
5. Successfully built Sitecore 9.3 assets using the command:

> docker image build --build-arg
>   BUILD_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903 --build-arg
>   BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903 --tag
>   sitecore-assets:9.3.0-nanoserver-1903 --isolation 'hyperv'
>   .\windows\9.3.0\sitecore-assets\

6. Successfully built OpenJDK nanoserver using the command:

> docker image build --build-arg
>   BUILD_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903 --build-arg
>   BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903 --tag
>   sitecore-openjdk:8-nanoserver-1903 --isolation 'hyperv'
>   .\windows\dependencies\sitecore-openjdk\

After building the OpenJDK, the next is to build Solr 8.1.1 using the OpenJDK as the BaseImage and it is where I'm struggling. The command I used for building Solr is:

> docker image build --build-arg
>   BUILD_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903 --build-arg
>   BASE_IMAGE=sitecore-openjdk:8-nanoserver-1903 --build-arg
>   SOLR_VERSION='8.1.1' --build-arg CORE_NAMES='sitecore_core_index,
>   sitecore_master_index, sitecore_web_index, sitecore_sxa_master_index,
>   sitecore_sxa_web_index' --tag sitecore-xm-solr:9.3.0-nanoserver-1903
>   --isolation 'hyperv' .\windows\9.x.x\sitecore-xm-solr\

However, I'm getting the below error each time I run the build command.

[image]